# Data not deleted from the sqlite3 table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new in ruby. I want to delete record. But unable to delete. Please check my code -

**ruby_win_sources/index.html.erb**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Url</th>
      <th colspan="3">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @ruby_win_sources.each do |ruby_win_source| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= ruby_win_source.name %></td>
        <td><%= ruby_win_source.author %></td>
        <td><%= ruby_win_source.url %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', ruby_win_source %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ruby_win_source_path(ruby_win_source) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', ruby_win_source, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**ruby_win_sources_controller.rb**

```
class RubyWinSourcesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ruby_win_source, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /ruby_win_sources
  # GET /ruby_win_sources.json
  def index
    @ruby_win_sources = RubyWinSource.all
  end

  # GET /ruby_win_sources/1
  # GET /ruby_win_sources/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /ruby_win_sources/new
  def new
    @ruby_win_source = RubyWinSource.new
  end

  # GET /ruby_win_sources/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /ruby_win_sources
  # POST /ruby_win_sources.json
  def create
    @ruby_win_source = RubyWinSource.new(ruby_win_source_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ruby_win_source.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ruby_win_source, notice: 'Ruby win source was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ruby_win_source }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @ruby_win_source.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ruby_win_sources/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ruby_win_sources/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ruby_win_source.update(ruby_win_source_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ruby_win_source, notice: 'Ruby win source was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ruby_win_source }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @ruby_win_source.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ruby_win_sources/1
  # DELETE /ruby_win_sources/1.json
  def destroy
    @ruby_win_source.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ruby_win_sources_url, notice: 'Ruby win source was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ruby_win_source
      @ruby_win_source = RubyWinSource.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ruby_win_source_params
      params.require(:ruby_win_source).permit(:name, :author, :url)
    end
end
```

Delete confirm box not opening.

Please help me

Edit - 
**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :ruby_win_sources
end
```

Comment: are you able to insert and update

Comment: Yes able to insert and update

Comment: Are you sure the `link_to ... method: :destroy` isn't supposed to be `:delete` ? Also, change `def destroy` to say `RubyWinSource.find(params[:id]).destroy`

Comment: so why you not call set_ruby_win_source method in delete instead of using instant  variable @ruby_win_source

Comment: ya right @DavidK-J

Comment: @Chinu can you please post your **routes.rb** ?

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Destroy', ruby_win_resource_path(ruby_win_source), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`  - can you just give it a try ? @Chinu

Comment: Error coming - `Showing d:/RoR/projects/demo/app/views/ruby_win_sources/index.html.erb where line #23 raised:

undefined method `ruby_win_resource_path' for #<#<Class:0x3a2bb80>:0x566d198>`

Comment: @dkp I have changed `ruby_win_resource_path` to `ruby_win_source_path` still not working

Comment: please change it to `ruby_win_source_path` - I just misread it.

Comment: yes i have hanged that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108391/discussion-between-chinu-and-dkp).

Comment: @Chinu what error you are getting now ? please add the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You drop your database `rake db:drop` and then rake `db:migrate` to create your tables

Comment: What has this to do with the question?

Comment: My database is working fine. I have added, updated, View successfully. But only problem is Record not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `delete` request while destroying an object:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', ruby_win_source, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Your controller looks good since you are setting

```
before_action :set_ruby_win_source, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

So you already have `@ruby_win_source` before `destroy` action gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your link_to to delete is incorrect and should be like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', ruby_win_source, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Then update your controller `destroy` method to:

```
# DELETE /ruby_win_sources/1
# DELETE /ruby_win_sources/1.json
def destroy
    RubyWinSource.find_by_id(params[:id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ruby_win_sources_url, notice: 'Ruby win source was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

Comment: A bit like my comment, or that answer from @dkp!

Comment: No same problem. While I am clicking Destroy link *delete confirmaton box* not coming. and page redirect to View page.